# django ValidationError not raised in test but raised in shell

Tags: python, django

I have a model defined below which invokes the manager in the clean() method.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from re import sub

class Vessel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stripped_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        stripped_name = sub(r'\s+', ' ', str(self.name).upper().strip())
        stripped_name = sub(r'^M[^a-zA-Z]*V\s*', '', stripped_name)
        stripped_name = sub(r'[^\w]', '', str(stripped_name).upper())
        self.stripped_name = stripped_name
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        stripped_name = sub(r'\s+', ' ', str(self.name).upper().strip())
        stripped_name = sub(r'^M[^a-zA-Z]*V\s*', '', stripped_name)
        stripped_name = sub(r'[^\w]', '', str(stripped_name).upper())
        if Vessel.objects.all().filter(stripped_name = stripped_name).exists():
            return ValidationError("Vessel name exists.")
```

In a freshly flushed shell, IntegrityError is raised fine.

```
>>> from my_random_app.models import Vessel
>>> vessel = Vessel(name='PM Hayabusa')
>>> vessel.save()
>>> vessel = Vessel(name=' M/V PM-HAYABUSA')
>>> vessel.save() # Raises IntegrityError
```

Even ValidationError is raised fine.

```
>>> from my_random_app.models import Vessel
>>> vessel = Vessel(name='PM Hayabusa')
>>> vessel.save()
>>> vessel = Vessel(name=' M/V PM-HAYABUSA')
>>> vessel.clean() # Raises ValidationError
```

But in the automated test, ValidationError is not raised.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
from django.test import TestCase

from my_random_app.models import Vessel

class  VesselTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_a(self):
        vessel = Vessel(name='PM Hayabusa')
        vessel.save()
        vessel = Vessel(name=' M/V PM-HAYABUSA')
        self.assertRaises(IntegrityError, vessel.save)

    def test_b(self):
        vessel = Vessel(name='PM Hayabusa')
        vessel.save()
        vessel = Vessel(name=' M/V PM-HAYABUSA')

        # This line FAILS!
        self.assertRaises(ValidationError, vessel.clean)
```

Is this related to how I call the manager in the clean() method? Why does the validation error raised in the shell but not in the test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is nearly perfect :)

ValidationError is an exception, some thing to raise, not intended to be returned.

If you replace `return` -> `raise` your problem will be solved.

```py
        if Vessel.objects.all().filter(stripped_name = stripped_name).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Vessel name exists.")
```

When you do it in the shell clean method returns the error so you think that it works fine but actually it is not.

```
>>> from my_random_app.models import Vessel
>>> vessel = Vessel(name='PM Hayabusa')
>>> vessel.save()
>>> vessel = Vessel(name=' M/V PM-HAYABUSA')
>>> vessel.clean() # Returns ValidationError
ValidationError(['Vessel name exists.'])
```

When it raises, it becomes as the floowing:

```
>>> from my_random_app.models import Vessel
>>> vessel = Vessel(name='PM Hayabusa')
>>> vessel.save()
>>> vessel = Vessel(name=' M/V PM-HAYABUSA')
>>> vessel.clean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/***/**/myapp/models.py", line 25, in clean
    raise ValidationError("Vessel name exists.")
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Vessel name exists.']
```